# jsf 2.0 Custom Component/Tag NOT COMPOSITE

Tags: java, jsf-2

Ok. I've looked everywhere for a simple example on how to create a custom jsf 2.0 custom component.

Basically, I am trying to create a tag that I can use, for example, inside panelGrid, series. etc.. that will display my own javasript. everything I have found is a tutorial on composite components, which are useless to me. I don't need to jumble a bunch of existing tags in a composite, i need to create my own.

does anyone know of any example code showing how to do this in 2.0. (no jsf 1.2)

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the Java EE 6 tutorial? http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnavg.html

Answer (score 8):

Look at [Creating Custom UI Components](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnavg.html) in The Java EE 6 Tutorial (as BalusC pointed). This applies to JSF 2 and describes creation of custom UI components (not composite components).

Comment: Aye! Thanks guys.. I've been searching for the wrong thing this whole time I guess.